# How to represent orbital velocity of a planet on an elliptical path in terms of time?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, computational-physics, planets, celestial-mechanics

Before reading this long message, please know that this is question is posted to know whether there is a method to find the relation between between the orbital velocity of a planet on an elliptical orbit and time.

I am trying to model the orbital velocity of Mercury orbiting the Sun on an **elliptical orbit**,that is the path of the orbit cannot be assumed to be circular as one might do at a high school level.

I have visited several sources online, I have tried to derive the equation myself and no matter what I do, I cannot seem to come up with an equation for this. I did come across the formula for orbital velocity in terms of the radius of orbit at any given instant; however, I could not use this to figure out a relationship between velocity and time either. The equation is as follows:
$$v=\sqrt {\frac{2GM}{r}-\frac{GM}{a}}$$
Where, $v$ is the orbital velocity, $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of Sun, $r$ is the orbital radius of a planet around the sun at any given instant (not constant on an elliptical path), and $a$ is the semimajor axis of the elliptical orbit.

On the other hand, when I tried deriving the equation, I got this differential equation:
[image: Differential equation]

Now, I tried solving this differential equation and I believe this is not solvable since the integral for the velocity terms is unsolvable (if I am correct). So, for this, I reached out to my Math teacher and asked her if I there was some other method to solve the differential equation and she suggested I use the [slope fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field) method. I tried it out but for some reason, this specific differential equation is not plotting out on any of the technology I used for plotting slope fields. Next I tried to plot these slope fields manually by the use of a graphing calculator and realized that the differential equation that for a particular range of $v$, $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is coming out to be complex.

So from here, I tried to find the range for which the value of $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is real; however, so far I have been unsuccessful. If someone can provide me with a pre-existing equation which describes this relation or knows a method derive the equation, or knows how to solve the differential equation mentioned above, it would be of great help to me.

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to plug all those raw numbers into your equations. It's much better to use symbolic constants, and only plug in actual numbers after you've done all the algebra & calculus.

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm for the calculation is as follows:

1. We call $t_0$ the time of passage through the perihelion and $T$ the orbital period. We first calculate the mean anomaly $M$ at the instant $t$ we want to know the velocity

$$M=\frac{2\pi}T \ (t-t_0)$$

2. From the mean anomaly we calculate the eccentric anomaly $E$ using Kepler's Equation. Because it is a transcendental equation, the calculation must be done by numerical methods, but it is a very simple calculation. Look, for example, [Kepler's Equation Fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation#Fixed-point_iteration)

$$E=M+e \sin E$$

3. Once the eccentric anomaly is known, we calculate the **true anomaly $\theta$ :

$$\tan \frac{\theta}2=\sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1-e}} \ \tan \frac E 2$$

4. From the true anomaly we calculate the distance $r$ to the Sun by means of:

$$r=\frac{a \ (1-e^2)}{1+e\cos \theta}$$

5. Finally, knowing the mass of the sun $M_s$, we calculate the velocity by means of:

$$v=\sqrt{2 G M_s \left (\frac 1 r - \frac 1{2a} \right )} $$

Best regards.

** If desired, it is possible "*to skip*" the calculation of the true anomaly by using directly the expression of the radius vector as a function of the eccentric anomaly:

$$r=a \ (1-e \cos E)$$

Comment: FWIW, I give the vis-viva equation of velocity in terms of the true anomaly $\theta$ in this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/675868/123208

Comment: related answer in Space SE to [What is the analytical closed-form solution of the two-body problem to verify its numerical integration results?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43237/12102)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use numeric values for position and velocity as a function of time, you might go for a computer generated simulation of the orbit.  There are various techniques for improving accuracy.  You might aim for an orbit that ends where it started.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the response; however, I had already tried what you have suggested. I picked up data from the NASA Horizons System and plotted the graph as well. The problem with this method is that even though the final function (v-t function) is periodic, it cannot be modelled by the usual periodic functions (trigonometric functions). I am not able to figure out what model suits those graphs best and therefore I am trying to derive the models on my own. Look at this question I asked on Math stack exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4337550/950470.

Comment: I like to do simulations on a spreadsheet.  It's easy to plot x and y coordinates using an orbit equation. Then use conservation of energy to get the speed at each point. With the speed, you can estimate the time to reach the next point.